# Error while entering the command phpdoc... phpdoc command is not found

Tags: phpdoc

I have installed the `phpDocumentor-2.7.0` on `ubuntu10.04`

But while entering the phpdoc command on terminal it shows the error as

**phpdoc:command not found**

I have installed according to http://www.phpdoc.org/

```
$ pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" is already initialized

$ pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
downloading phpDocumentor-2.7.0.tgz ...
Starting to download phpDocumentor-2.7.0.tgz (16,118,916 bytes)
............................................................done: 16,118,916 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor-2.7.0

$ phpdoc
phpdoc:command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your PEAR configuration does not have its "bin_dir" configuration set in a way that your shell's PATH includes it.

`pear config-show` to see what bin_dir is set to.

`echo $PATH` to see if it contains that bin_dir value